# How do I correct PhpStorm when it guesses the wrong parameters for JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, ide, comments, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

Looking around [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2012/10/validating-javascript-code-with-jsdoc-types-annotations/) seems to be the closest it comes to being an answer to my problem. However it causes other issues...

---

This is my situation:

```
$element.insertBefore($container);
```

This line has a warning that `insertBefore` has an “*Invalid number of arguments, expected 2*”

```
/** @type {function(target)} */
$element.insertBefore;
$element.insertBefore($container);
```

These three lines have a warning, but for a different reason. The third line no longer has any warning about an invalid number of arguments; however the second line is now concerned that the “*Expression statement is not assignment or call*”.

I tried a number of other configurations however none of them seem to affect the first warning in any way… but they don’t create new warnings.
Some of these variations are as follows:

```
/** @type {function(target)} */
/* $element.insertBefore; */
$element.insertBefore($container);
```

—

```
/** @type {function(target)}
$element.insertBefore; */
$element.insertBefore($container);
```

—

```
/** @type {function(target)} */
$element.insertBefore($container);
```

I was just wondering if anyone could give me pointers on what I’m doing wrong or if this warning is just an irreversible mistake for the system right now.

**P.S. This is actually JavaScript code… I just have a habit of prefacing variables that are instances of jQuery objects with a dollar sign. This means that the above calls to `insertBefore` are calls to the jQuery function not the vanilla JavaScript function.**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like *insertBefore()* does require 2 parameters: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

Comment: The default vanilla javascript function does require 2 parameters, but the jQuery function `insertBefore` only requires one. The code works fine, but the phpStorm warning remains.

Comment: Right, then it would be most efficient to report it to the official bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB#newissue=yes